# Pack and Unpack in C/Python

Tags: c, python-2.7, pack

I'm working with sockets in a client/server model (client in Python and server in C ) and I have to send some data from the client to the server so I'm using :

```
packed_data= pack('B5s5s50s',0x21,extension.strip(),pin,'')
```

to pack de data I want to send, but

I don't have any idea how I have to **unpack this data in C working with the server.**

Comment: is this `struct.pack`? How did you try to unpack this in your C code?

Comment: This is the problem. I know how to pack/unpack data in python but no in C so I don't know which code use..

Comment: Do you know how to read bytes from a socket in C?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of the `struct` module your message will always have a fixed length of 61 bytes. Therefore, you'd read 61 bytes from the socket into an appropriate container in order to unpack this in a C application.

Here's some untested example code:

```
unsigned char buf[61] = {0};
read(sockfd, buf, sizeof(buf));
// print contents:
printf("%#2x\n", buf[0]);
for (i=1; i<6; i++) printf("%#2x ", buf[i]); printf("\n");
for (i=6; i<11; i++) printf("%#2x ", buf[i]); printf("\n");
for (i=11; i<61; i++) printf("%#2x ", buf[i]); printf("\n");
```

For reference:

- http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html
- http://linux.die.net/man/3/read
- http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf

Comment: This return me a message like this:

0x32 0x31 0x30 0x35  0 
0x75 0x73 0x65 0x72 0x30 
0x35  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 

How can I "Translate" this in our language? Because this is hexadecimal no?

Comment: @user3374320 These are the transmitted characters in their hexadecimal representation. Try to adapt the [`printf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) invocation to print the character/string representation of the data. Otherwise you could also look up the characters in an ASCII-table: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters